# How to activate scrolling for the Kensington Slimblade Trackball?

Tags: mouse, xinput, peripherals

I've got the Kensington Slimblade Trackball, I've just plugged in, it works fine for moving the cursor, right and left clicking, middle click and also the 4th button which works as a back button.

However, how do I do scrolling?

Can I map one of the buttons to enable a "scroll mode"?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont wanna sound stupid but did you try turning the ball like a big volume button?

I still use Bionic Beaver and its plug and play.

Comment: You know what, I had not, I discovered days after writing this post that the ball turning did scroll, haha!! Thanks for leaving a comment! I'm now using a mix of both, because I find that the scrolling I've configured makes it easier in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, you can use the `xinput` too to configure the behavior of `libinput`, the library used to handle input devices.

I run these two commands to enable scrolling for my Slimblade trackball using the back button:

```
xinput set-prop 'Kensington Slimblade Trackball' 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0, 0, 1
xinput set-prop 'Kensington Slimblade Trackball' 'libinput Button Scrolling Button' 8
```

It will then behave like this: if you press and scroll it will only scroll, if you just click it it will work as back button.

The first command enables the scrolling behavior, and the second command tells it to use the back button (instead of button 2, the same used for middle-click -- which makes for an awkward position to click and scroll if you're using the Trackball right-handed).

In case your trackball isn't the same model, you can run the same commands replacing `'Kensington Slimblade Trackball'` by the corresponding id or name of your device you have that you can see when running `xinput list`.

See [`man libinput`](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput) for more details.

Comment: For what is worth, this post should be the accepted answer, since it's exactly the correct answer to the specific question, even though the other one may have been what the O.P. _needed to know_.  The wording of the question, however, _really_ needs an answer like this one here, for someone looking for it, like me, so I am lucky to have found this post. This is not to criticize **in any way** the selected answer, quite entirely the opposite: it obviously is a very useful answer too and it did fix a problem! To be fair, _both_ answers in a single post would have been perfect.